# Rails tutorial Ch11 - No route matches [POST] "/signup"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following railstutorial chapter 11.
Just finished [Listing 11.24](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation#code-comment_out_failing_tests) and created new user expecting to get redirected to root_url and willing to look for  account activation email in sever log (which is I guess `log/development.log`).

I thought I made a typo in `routes.rb` but error persists even when I copy pasted his version and restarted server. I don't see post '/signup' route there either. Most recent version of `routes.rb` is in [Listing 11.1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation#code-account_activations_route)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `POST /signup` so that error is correct.

If you look at 11.24 careful, you will see it posts to `users_path`, e.g. for the first test case:

```
post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "",
                                   email: "user@invalid",
                                   password:              "foo",
                                   password_confirmation: "bar" } }
```

`users_path` is defined in 11.1 by `resources :users` which refers to a `POST /users` defined by `UserController#create`, shown in 11.23.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: So what are you saying? There is an error in tutorial? How come tests work and in development server I get that error?

Comment: No, like I said, look at `11.24` carefully, the tutorial never uses `POST /signup` at all, it uses `POST /users` as defined like I showed.

Comment: By filling out a form in `/users/new`, I get redirected to `/post/signup`. Why? Where can I find that code?

Comment: Where is your /users/new form? At a guess its because you use `signup_path` when you should have used `users_path`.

Comment: Yes I have in `new.html.erb` this code: `form_for(@user, url: signup_path)`. Not sure where is that from, been a few days since last chapter.

Comment: Why the `url: signup_path`? That is your error, and its not how the tutorial does it. See https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#code-signup_form  But if you do want to rename it, you do need to then add another route manually (`post "signup", to: "users#create"`)

Comment: You are right, I have started the exercise related to listing 10.5, couldn't finish it within 10 minutes, aborted and forgot to change the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you only have a get route for your /signup (that's meant to serve the form for the user to enter their info. The route you are missing is

```
post    '/signup',  to: 'users#create'
```

Because you created a `create` action inside the `UsersController`.

Comment: 11.1 had a `resources :users` which creates a `post` route by default.

Comment: Yes, but judging by your error you are expecting a `POST /signup` and not `POST /users` as the `resources: :users` creates.

Comment: Yes, but while Marko is trying to do that, its not actually what the book he linked is saying to do at all, the book does `post users_path`, which is `POST /users` not `POST /signup`.

Comment: I agree, I went straight with the error and wasn't exactly worried about what the tutorial said.